# How to display the search result score as percentage in the frontend?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I've recently set up `Elasticsearch` on my Django project using `Django-haystack` and I want to display the search results' scores as percentages in my templates (html).

So I am wondering if there's a way to achieve this?

A quick example of the final result would be this:

```
<div>
{% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20">

        {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

        <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">


<!-- Matching score to be displayed in the h5 below -->

          <h5>{{result.object.matching_score}}</h5>

        <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
          <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
          <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
        </a>

        </div>

         {% endfor %}
       </ol>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

I'm still new to this but maybe an `If - Else` statement, the Elasticsearch default `_score` value or even some Javascript might do the job. I'm not sure, so what do you think I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If `matching_scroe` is what you want to show as a percentage you can do it using `{{result.object.matching_score|floatformat:2}}%`

If you have 2 values that need dividing you need to write a template tag

In directory `templatetags`, `mytags.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def div(numerator, denominator):
    return float(numerator/denominator)
```

In your html file

```
{% load mytags %}

{{ object.numerator|div:object.denominator }}%
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Your answer will definitly be helpful but first I need to find out how to actually give a score to the search results and then display it. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I'm aware that Elasticsearch gives a default _score value like this: https://imgur.com/MkwKfpC  (Took a screenshot of my index and Highlighted the _score value as an example). So maybe I could write a custom python code in my Django project to retrieve this _score value and change it into a percentage and finally call it in my html?

Comment: sounds like a sensible approach

Comment: Yes I know, the goal is to achieve something like this: https://imgur.com/uYNsZtr

Comment: What should I do?